# How to enable tilt with react-native-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps. My question is short. So how can I set initial camera horizontal  position as fallow at image?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To tilt the map and view from another perspective, use `animateToViewingAngle`.

I am aware that it is inherently supported by iOS, so you should expect this behavior by default on iOS. However, I am not sure about Android.

More information, please visit this [GitHub Thread](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/pull/1544).

Comment: Hi Rex, I used that one but its only for the lat and long position am I wrong? ` this.map.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.latitude,
      longitude: location.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0029397161733585335,
      longitudeDelta: 0.002845874547958374,
    }); `

Comment: @UğurErdal You should be able to define an initial location with this props. `this.map.animateToRegion` is used to render next location with a bit of animation. Can you elaborate your problem more?

Comment: I tried as you said but its doesn't work. My problem is you can scrool using two finger to upper side on the screen. At the that time for example the buildings seems like 3d.  So I wanna do that. when the map is open. It should open default like 3d (I dont know what the name of 3d things. as in the image ) @rex-low

Comment: Also the props name is `pitchEnabled` btw.

Comment: I found it man `animateToViewingAngle()`  its work as I want. thanx for your work

Comment: Haha looks like we found the solution at the same time ;)

Comment: @UğurErdal Please accept the answer if you find it helpful. Also, please update your original question so that others may benefit from our findings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that works for me

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView 
          showsBuildings
          ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
          onLayout={() => {
            this.map.animateToBearing(125);
            this.map.animateToViewingAngle(45);
          }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 41.8781,
            longitude: -87.6298,
            latitudeDelta: 1 / 300,
            longitudeDelta: 2 / 300
          }}
          style={styles.mapStyle}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```

snack demo https://snack.expo.io/Sym1DTm0r (working as for Dec 2019)

[image]